When does "the share of" equal "the percentage of"?
So I've found some examples where "the share of" has a similar meaning to "the percentage of".

1.The fracking boom and a more modest clean-energy boom have increased this country’s share of energy production and held down costs worldwide. (source)
2. His share of the vote rose by 15 percentage points among Hispanics. (source)
3. Engel's law' states that as income increases, the share of expenditure on food in total household expenditure tends to decrease. (source)
4. Since 2000, the proportion of the prison population made up of whites and blacks had declined slightly; the share of Hispanics increased. (source)

What do these examples have in common? According to many dictionaries, share is a part of something that has been divided between several people or things. I think this meaning is only related to the 2nd and 3rd examples. In the 1st and 4th examples, I don't think energy production or prison population is shared between anybody or anything.
So, what kinds of nouns can go with "the share of" and create phrases which have a similar meaning to "the percentage of something"?
P.S. I would love it if your answer includes an explanation regarding specifically to example 4. That's the most confusing one out of all. Thank you!

A percentage of something is a share of something.  They all mean percentage in your examples. Obviously, not the verb: We shared a quiet moment by the river.

There is no need for a share to be owned or controlled by a person, it applies equally well to a split among almost any kind of entity - a country, family, corporation, or group can all have a share of something. "Market share," for example, refers to the size of the market controlled by a company.

@NuclearHoagie market share is also a  percentage.

I understand that it's not necessarily shared between people, but I still don't understand example 4. There's nothing shared here. It's not even mareket share.

@anIELTSlearner - You are thinking of shared as a verb.  Shared in this response has nothing to with giving or allocating.  Share is a noun in this case, meaning a portion.  The prison population is shared among ethnic groups.

There's another post in this forum discussing the use of "share". I think @FumbleFingers' made a comment opposite to what people are saying here. Here's the link.

All those sentences are fine. In economics and statistics, the word share is a synonyms for percentage or part.

These are both ways of talking about parts of a whole. There are others, like "the fraction of" or "portion of."
As you point out, they can often be swapped for each other without changing the meaning, as long as the point is simply that it is a part of a whole. But be careful as they each have literal meanings, and there could be literal contexts where one is best. For instance, "fraction" and "percentage" have different mathematical meanings. If we said...

This pie has been cut into fourths. Billy takes one piece and Bobby takes the rest. What percentage does Bobby take?

... then a very strict math teacher might not count "3/4" as a correct answer, only "75%."
Similarly, "share" has a connotation that something has been "shared" among people. It's used idiomatically in the phrase "your fair share" (perhaps because it rhymes), and while "Hey, you took more than your fair fraction!" would be understandable, it would be un-idiomatic.
But in the statistical contexts you give, all are essentially interchangeable.

fraction and portion do not work in those sentences.

I've once used "the share of" before and many said that it was very unnatural. I think it also talked about the share of a group of people like in example 4. I still don't get why it is suddenly okay in example 4 here.

'Share' and 'percentage' are not the same thing, even though they could sometimes both be used to describe the same thing.

A 'share' is an allocated portion of something. It usually indicates ownership or responsibility - something that belongs to a person or people. One's share in something could be measured by a percentage, or by any other means.
A percentage is one of many ways to indicate a rate or share of something.

Here's a situation where they could mean the same thing. Let's say three children all inherit equal amounts in their parents' will. You could say that they all had an equal share, or that they all received 33.3 percent of the estate. You could also say they all received a third.
But let's say you were comparing the number of elephants and giraffes in a zoo. There are 3 elephants and 4 giraffes. You could express that as a percentage - 42.86% of the animals are elephants, 57.14% are giraffes. But that's not really a "share" of anything. There's nothing to own, nothing to allocate. So that word just doesn't fit the context.
Further, it is possible to have a "share" of something without it being measured. Let's say 4 friends agree to share a large pizza. The slices might be different sizes. There might be some left over. Nobody really keeps tabs on what they eat. You could say they all had a 'share', but there's no way to express that as a percentage.
Also note that shares can be expressed as fractions (a percentage is just a fraction with a denominator of 100) and sometimes as a ratio where there are only two shares.

In the context of your sentence 4., "share" is used as a synonym for "proportion".
Note: I can't find a reputable dictionary that gives this definition, so I can only give you my word as a native speaking veteran ESL teacher that I'm confident of the meaning, and that it's correct and natural as used there by the New York Times because it's explicitly used as a synonym to avoid repeating "proportion".
It would be less natural to mean "proportion" in a context where the word hadn't been used yet. You might say it's mildly poetic, which is perhaps why it doesn't appear in dictionaries, even though it is used that way.

So to sum up, if there are several groups of things/people that comprise the entirety of something, I can first say "the proportion of [a certain group]" and then later change it to "the share of [a certain group]", no matter what type of things/people they are?

@anIELTSlearner "no matter what" is a strong phrase, but yes, I think that should work.

Thanks. Could you please have a look at the link I commented above to see why the other user found that "the share of" was incorrect in that case?

@anIELTSlearner If you're talking about FF's comment, the question he's talking about doesn't use "proportion" or some other word first. I can only speculate that if he saw that NYT example that he'd agree it was natural and correct. It could also be that in BrE "share" cannot be used as I've described in my answer, but that would surprise me.


When does "the share of" equal "the percentage of"?

Any time "share" is being used to describe a part/portion of a "whole" you could probably substitute the word "percentage" and be understood. While the implied meanings are slightly different, the differences in the examples you provided aren't significant enough in typical speech/writing to be an issue. In technical writing this could be an issue though.
The examples you provided use "Share" to mean:

a portion belonging to, due to, or contributed by an individual or group
a portion belonging to, due to, or contributed by an individual or group
a portion belonging to, due to, or contributed by an individual or group
a portion belonging to, due to, or contributed by an individual or group

I took the exact definition from Merriam-Webster, but you can interpret "due to" to also cover "attributed to".
"Share" is a very versatile word in English, so not all definitions may be covered. Collins Dictionary makes a little more effort to cover some variations though.

Thanks. So you mean to say that FumbleFingers' comment on this post is incorrect?

I admittedly disagree with FumbleFingers on that point. He is right in that "proportion" is likely the better word there, but "the share of" shouldn't be confusing to the majority of English speakers. In the context of a test, it's hard to say whether "the share of" is considered the correct answer. The test may use the logic that there are better options than "the share of", so I can't say for sure what is expected.
